# Enhancer function that changes the type of the first parameter?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Here is an higher order `logFunctionName` function that enhances `say` by logging the function name. The enhanced `enhancedSay` function takes the same arguments as the original `say` function.

```
function say(msg: string | number) {
  console.log(msg)
}

function logFunctionName<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: T): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {
  return (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    console.log(func.name)
    return func(...args);
  };
}

const enhancedSay = logFunctionName(say)("hello");

// const enhancedSay2 = messageLength(say)("hello");
// => 5
```

Now I am stuck at a problem.

How would I write a higher order `messageLength` function that enhances `say` by converting the first argument passed to it from a string to a number representing the length of the string. The enhanced `enhancedSay2` function takes a string, while the original `say` function gets a number.

EDIT: This is a simplified example. What I really want to do is create a higher order function that takes a string, injects this string into the DOM and passes on an element to the enhanced function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't make the function generic in the function type but in its parameter types and return type, that should give some room to fiddle:

```
function messageLength<P extends any[], R>(func: (len: number, ...args:T) => R): (msg: string, ...args: P) => R {
  return (msg, ...args) => {
    return func(msg.length, ...args);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for what looks to be a very good solution. Feel very welcome to write an explanation of what is happening in your answer.

Comment: @user1283776 What parts do you feel need more explanation?